# Errors while building Lupa (Probably an issue with pkg-config)

Tags: python, windows, lua, mingw, pkg-config

I'm trying to compile [lupa](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lupa) on Windows 7 64bit, and I've installed all of the dependencies (including LuaJIT2 and Lua 5.2). But when I try to install, I get this error:

> RuntimeError: Neither LuaJIT2 nor Lua 5.1 were found, please install
>   the library  and its development packages, or put a local build into
>   the lupa main directory  (or pass '--no-luajit' option)

It's confusing me also because it checks for Lua 5.2 as well as 5.1, but complains that I don't have 5.1.

> Checking for installed lua5.2 library using pkg-config
>   Did not find lua5.2 using pkg-config: pkg-config cannot find an installed lua5.2
>
> Checking for installed lua-5.2 library using pkg-config
>   Did not find lua-5.2 using pkg-config: pkg-config cannot find an installed lua-5 .2
>
> Checking for installed lua library using pkg-config
>   Did not find lua using pkg-config: pkg-config cannot find an installed lua
>
> Checking for installed lua5.1 library using pkg-config
>   Did not find lua5.1 using pkg-config: pkg-config cannot find an installed lua5.1
>
> Checking for installed lua-5.1 library using pkg-config
>   Did not find lua-5.1 using pkg-config: pkg-config cannot find an installed lua-5 .1
>
> Checking for installed lua library using pkg-config
>   Did not find lua using pkg-config: pkg-config cannot find an installed lua

I'm quite sure at this point that this is an issue with pkg-config. I looked inside the setup.py and it uses pkg-config to test if the package is there, and to get the version. pkg-config when run directly from the console can not find any packages. When I look for one (in this case LuaJIT2), I just get this:

> Package luajit was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `luajit.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'luajit' found

There is no environment variable named `PG_CONFIG_PATH`, and adding it manually didn't work.
Please help, I'm stumped. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to unzip the LuaJIT package into the base directory of LUPA.

If lupa is located at "D:\project\lupa1.1", you need to put the LuaJIT into that dir, like this, "D:\project\lupa1.1\LuaJIT-2.0.3".

Try it and good luck!